# matplotlib: axes size in pixels of png image

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, png

I want to generate a png image where the x-axis spans a given number of pixels.

With the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], [0,1])
new_pixels_in_axes = 1000 * np.diff(ax.get_xlim())[0]
dpi_calculated = new_pixels_in_axes / ax.bbox.width * fig.dpi
plt.savefig('dpi_calculated.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=dpi_calculated)
plt.savefig('dpi_corrected.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=dpi_calculated / 1.1)
```

I get two images. I expected to have 1000 pixels in the x-axis of the first image (dpi_calculated.png), but that's not true. I get the desired pixels in the axis of the image dpi_corrected.png.

Can anybody explain why is this? I cannot find anything in the documentation that explains the difference.